# Finding expectation and variance of stochastic integral from given SDE

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am given the following interest rate model with SDE: $dX_t=\alpha \,dt+\sigma \,dB_t$ where $α$ and $σ$ are constants, and $B_t$ is a Brownian motion. I am supposed to determine
$$
E\left[ \int_0^T X_t \,dt\right] \quad\text{ and }\quad V \left[\int_0^T X_t \,dt\right]
$$
Any clues? I am lost. I am able to work out SDE from a given function using Ito's formula and then apply stochastic integrals. But I have no idea for this qns.

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly,
\begin{align}
X_t&=X_0+\alpha\,t+\sigma\,B_t\,,\\
E[X_t]&=X_0+\alpha\,t\,,\\
E[X_uX_v]&=(X_0+\alpha\,u)(X_0+\alpha\,v)+\sigma^2\min(u,v)\,.\tag{1}
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$\tag{2}
E\left[\int_0^TX_t\,dt\right]=\int_0^TE[X_t]\,dt=X_0T+\frac{\alpha T^2}{2}\,.
$$
To find the variance we can first calculate
$$\tag{3}
E\left[\left(\int_0^TX_t\,dt\right)^2\right]=\int_0^T\int_0^TE[X_uX_v]\,du\,dv\,
$$
and use
$$
V\left[\int_0^TX_s\,ds\right]=E\left[\left(\int_0^TX_t\,dt\right)^2\right]
-\underbrace{E\left[\int_0^TX_s\,ds\right]^2}_{(X_0T+\frac{\alpha T^2}{2})^2\text{ by (1) }}\,.
$$
Using (1) the calculation of (3) is straightforward.